# invalid_request 400 bad request

Tags: identityserver4

This is my `ConfigureServices` method of my Identity Server project.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddIdentityServer()
      .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
      .AddOperationalStore(options =>
      {
          options.EnableTokenCleanup = true;
          options.TokenCleanupInterval = 30; // interval in seconds
      })
      .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
      .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
        .AddTestUsers(Config.GetUsers())
        .AddProfileService<DefaultProfileService>();
    }
```

When I follow the tutorial, the tutorial uses `.AddProfileService<ProfileService>()` but I could not find `ProfileService`. So I use `DefaultProfileService`. Could the error due to this?

and in my `config.cs`

public class Config
{
public static IEnumerable GetApiResources()
{
return new List
{
new ApiResource("myresourceapi", "My Resource API")
{
Scopes = {new Scope("apiscope")}
}
};
}

```
    public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
    {
        return new[]
        {
            // for public api
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "secret_client_id",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
                ClientSecrets =
                {
                    new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                },
                AllowedScopes = { "apiscope" }
            },
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "secret_user_client_id",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword,
                ClientSecrets =
                {
                    new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                },
                AllowedScopes = { "apiscope" }
            }
        };
    }

    public static List<TestUser> GetUsers()
    {
        return new List<TestUser>
        {
            new TestUser
            {
                SubjectId = "1",
                Username = "user",
                Password = "user",
                Claims = new[]
                {
                    new Claim("roleType", "CanReaddata")
                }
            },
            new TestUser
            {
                SubjectId = "2",
                Username = "admin",
                Password = "admin",
                Claims = new[]
                {
                    new Claim("roleType", "CanUpdatedata")
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

When I test it at Postman, I got the error `invalid_request`

[image]

I have tested another client id `ClientId = "secret_client_id"` and it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `AddTestUser` then you don't need to add a profile service as it adds one for you that works with the test users:

```
public static IIdentityServerBuilder AddTestUsers(this IIdentityServerBuilder builder, List<TestUser> users)
{
    builder.Services.AddSingleton(new TestUserStore(users));
    builder.AddProfileService<TestUserProfileService>();
    builder.AddResourceOwnerValidator<TestUserResourceOwnerPasswordValidator>();

    return builder;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out that my problem is I issued a `GET` request which should be a `POST` request.